# Aerospike : Delete all bins

Tags: aerospike, nosql

I am trying to delete bins from my set.
The thing is when I delete them, they are still shown in

```
aql> show bins
+-------+------------------+-------+-----------+
| quota | bin              | count | namespace |
+-------+------------------+-------+-----------+
| 32768 | "family"         | 14    | "test"    |
| 32768 | "querybinstring" | 14    | "test"    |
| 32768 | "querybinint"    | 14    | "test"    |
| 32768 | "binstringfoo"   | 14    | "test"    |
+-------+------------------+-------+-----------+
```

though the data has been deleted from the set.

```
aql> select * from test.testset
0 rows in set (0.000 secs)
```

The issue arises when my **binNames reaches 32k limit of unique binNames constraint**.
I ***have to restart*** aerospike for the deleted bin names to be really gone.

So is there any other way than to restart after deleting bins ?
What really happens when aerospike is restarted ? (which deletes the deleted [marked as deleted] bins )

Note : I have tested this by deleting the bins using

1. client.delete()
2. set expiration

One more question - Is there any way I can delete **all bins** from a set through **aql** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Methods to Delete meta data in Aerospike

Take a look at this discussion forum for a good list of methods to delete meta data of bins in Aerospike.

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/bin-names-deletion/731

- Deleting Bin from AQL

You can delete a bin using AQL by setting it to NULL

E.g: Insert into namespace.set (PK, bin) values ('1', NULL)
will delete bins from records with primary key '1'

- Understanding Deletion in general

Aerospike separates the data into two parts: index and value. The index is always stored in DRAM, the value can be stored in either SSD or DRAM (with or without disk for persistence). When a record is deleted, the reference to it is removed from the index. The actual data is not removed from the disk. Another process will find that the data on disk is not being used and reclaim the space.

Note that it is possible for deleted object to reappear. For this to happen the following has to occur:

The node must be configured to load data from disk. And if data has been deleted, but not yet removed from disk. (i.e. the index entry has been removed). In this case when the node starts, it will read the data from disk and rebuild the index. Because the data has not been removed from disk, the node will think it is still active and build a new index entry for it. So the deleted object will return. If you know you will be taking down a node, you can prevent deleted data from returning by using the fast restart feature. This will hold the index in memory even when the database process has gone down.

Another option in newer releases is by using 'cold-start-empty' configuration which prevents data to be loaded from disk, but only by migration from other nodes in the cluster.

More information here:
http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#cold-start-empty

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. To answer my questions -  

 1.  *Is there any way I can delete all bins from a set through aql ?* - So there is no way to delete **ALL BINS** through aql. Something like DELETE * from namespace.set   
 2.  *So is there any other way than to restart after deleting bins ?* - I guess your answer is no.
 3.  *What really happens when aerospike is restarted ?* -  
"*The actual data is not removed from the disk. Another process will find that the data on disk is not being used and reclaim the space*" - This another process is run **only at restart**

Comment: 1. You are right, there is no way to delete all bins via aql (or via other means). 2. Unfortunately, as of today, there is no way to delete bins without restart (coldstart) but it is easy to come up with this minor feature. Please keep a watch for this change to come. 3. When the node is coldstarted (not simple restart which may be a warmstart/fastrestart), the Metadata of bin names is rebuilt by scanning the disk. As the deleted bin will not be found on any valid record on the disk, it will not make it to the newly rebuilt Metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Every keyspace you create will be part of data folder of Aerospike . You can delete that file directly.

This is one of the easy methods we found to delete all the data at once.

```
folder loc :: /opt/aerospike/usr/
```